# $state.go is not working from separate controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is my Code

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
url: "/home",
templateUrl: "views/home.tpl.html",
controller:"homeController"
})
.state('test', {
url: '/test',
templateUrl: "views/test/dashboard.tpl.html",

});
```

My modal view in index.html page is

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="userController">
    <form ng-submit="login()" >
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My userController function is

```
$scope.login = function(){

     console.log($scope.user);
     if($scope.user.email=="xxxx" && $scope.user.password=="123456"){

         $state.go("test");


     }

 }
```

Angular js is throwing error as

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at l.$scope.login (http://localhost/yyy/scripts/controllers/userController.js:15:19)
    at ib.functionCall

The state is not transferred. Please let me know where i am wrong

Comment: did you inject $state in your userController controller?

Comment: See if you injected $state as mentioned by @levi. If yes, which is line 15 in your controller?

Comment: yes.$state is injected

Comment: $state.go("test"); --Line 15

Comment: check your ui-router version

Comment: I have called the userController seperately from the form. Is that creating the problem. If yes, how can i call two controllers in app.js itself

Comment: * State-based routing for AngularJS
 * @version v0.2.13 ....................................... ui-router $state.go is working fine if i use it in homecontroller. Its not working only from usercontroller

Comment: Providing a Plunk or Jsfiddle link will be more helpful.

Comment: It works fine with plunk. I am uploading my project files to GIT.I would appreciate if you could clone and it and help me why is it not working with project files.

Comment: Here is my github page. https://github.com/alaksandarjesus/mockuponline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I found my mistake.

Earlier it was

```
myApp.controller('userController',['$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$stateParams', '$state', function ($scope,$http,$rootScope,$state, $stateParams)
```

and changed to

```
myApp.controller('userController',['$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope,$http,$rootScope,$state, $stateParams)
```

The injection of stateParams and state were not in order and that threwup the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I had the same problem but it would never had dawned on me in a 1000 years that the order of the services had to be so specific.

Comment: are you missing a closing braket?

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you injected ui.router in your angular module

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

Comment: Yep.I injected it. As i am using it as a modal login form, its not working. If i have it in another view its working. Guide me how to change states from modal form. Kindly go through my code again.